# Why is "could" used in “I am glad that you could make it?”

Tags: modal-verbs

Grammar books say don’t use *could* for past performance. For example, if I ran after a bus and caught it, I can’t say “I ran after a bus and could catch it.”

Nevertheless, people say “I am glad that you could make it” to their guests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking directly about something that happened in the past, you just use simple past:

> I ran after a bus and caught it.

If you describe the same event in a that-clause, you have the option of focusing on the **ability** to do something, rather than on the doing itself, for example:

> I was pleased that I **could** run fast enough to catch the bus. - *ability*
>   I was pleased that I caught the bus. - *completion*

Likewise, when you say

> I am glad that you **could** make it
>   I am disappointed that I **could** not attend the funeral
>   I am happy that I **could** help.

you are focusing on the ability to do it, not actually doing it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case of the use of the modal verb *could* in all types of written and spoken speech, which has the following meaning: *I am glad that circumstances so developed that you were able to come finally.* This expression has a hint of slight friendly reproach.

This meaning of the modal verb could be close to its other meaning, when it indicates that something sometimes happened, for example, *Someone could be a good person if he/she wanted to.*